# Files and their headers?

Tags: command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt, headers

*(I'm a dos guy , I always liked to view files in norton commander and see inside stuff etc)*

however over the years I've noticed that each file(well , most of) ( binary files ) has header :

For example exe file has the MZ header  :

[image]

PGP file has also a header ;

[image]

Pdf file has also a header ;

[image]

ZIP file has also a header ;

[image]

etc

So my question : is there any complete list of those headers ? where can i find it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Linux system the file `/usr/share/misc/magic` is the source for the `magic.mgc` file used by the [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command. I doubt it's complete for every file type though.

The format of the file is described in the [magic](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) man pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such complete list, because there is no central registry or authority for file headers. Any of these could be re-used by some new company with a new file format.

Comment: IMHO - this has nothing to do with registry. those headers was much before event MS knew what is registry. it's more a stamp of a file. So I dont think there is a connection to windows shell extensions in regisrty.

Comment: I did not capitalize the word "registry", because I was not referring to the Windows Registry. If you want a public domain name that doesn't overlap with anyone else's, you have to purchase it from a domain name registrar. There is no such analogous organization for file headers.

Comment: oh sorry. language barrier ...:-)